# session_start and Dreamweaver templates

Tags: php, templates, dreamweaver

- `session_start()` should be the first line of web page.
- Dreamweaver's php templates should be used inside the HTML tag (so, obviously this is not the first line).

  What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use dreamweaver for php programming.

Comment: aptana/eclipse/netbeans... i bet there are a lot of discussions here about PHP IDEs (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ide)

Comment: it's your wish, but by selecting weird tool be ready to get weird behavior, as you already got ;-)

Comment: web templates == wysiwyg for generating unsupportable and invalid html markup with just mouse? nope. aptana is the tool for **developers**, not for people who know nothing and don't want to learn.

Comment: Dreamweaver is good if you use it only as a text editor and FTP tool.

Comment: @serhio: nope. for first time include will be enough cool for you. later you will know how **developers** solve such problems.

Comment: @serhio: so don't be so ironic by asking "You mean that "developers" should manually copy paste the same code". you know that it false, do you? the selected IDE doesn't specify the how you should do your work - it just makes your work simpler and faster.